# Clear lower 16 bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm not so good with bitwise operators so please excuse the question but how would I clear the lower 16 bits of a 32-bit integer in C/C++?

For example I have an integer: 0x12345678 and I want to make that: 0x12340000

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To clear any particular set of bits, you can use bitwise AND with the complement of a number that has 1s in those places.  In your case, since the number 0xFFFF has its lower 16 bits set, you can AND with its complement:

```
b &= ~0xFFFF; // Clear lower 16 bits.
```

If you wanted to **set** those bits, you could instead use a bitwise OR with a number that has those bits set:

```
b |= 0xFFFF; // Set lower 16 bits.
```

And, if you wanted to **flip** those bits, you could use a bitwise XOR with a number that has those bits set:

```
b ^= 0xFFFF; // Flip lower 16 bits.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is actually nice because it works with 16 and 64-bit values also, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @James- If you try doing something like `b & 0xFFFF0000` on a non-32 bit machine (for example, a 64-bit machine), then this might accidentally end up clearing the high 32 bits in addition to the low 32 bits.

Comment: It does not work with 64-bit values. `0xffff` has type `int` which is almost surely 32-bit in real-world systems even if `b` has type `unsigned long` or such. Also, `~0xffff` has implementation-defined behavior since `0xffff` has signed type. See my answer for a better approach.

Comment: Can you please tell what if 0x12345678 and I want to make that: 0x00005678, or should I open another question ?

Answer (score 4):

To take another path you can try

```
x = ((x >> 16) << 16);
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to bitwise AND it with 0xFFFF0000 e.g.  `value = value & 0xFFFF0000`

Answer (score 1):

Use an *and* (`&`) with a mask that is made of the top 16 bit all ones (that will leave the top bits as they are) and the bottom bits all zeros (that will kill the bottom bits of the number).

So it'll be

```
0x12345678 & 0xffff0000
```

If the size of the type isn't known and you want to mask out only the lower 16 bits you can also build the mask in another way: use a mask that would let pass only the lower 16 bits

```
0xffff
```

and invert it with the bitwise not (`~`), so it will become a mask that *kills* only the lower 16 bits:

```
0x12345678 & ~0xffff
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = 0x12345678;
int mask = 0xffff0000;

x &= mask;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the value you want to clear bits from has an unsigned type not of "small rank", this is the safest, most portable way to clear the lower 16 bits:

```
b &= -0x10000;
```

The value `-0x10000` will be promoted to the type of `b` (an unsigned type) by modular arithmetic, resulting in all high bits being set and the low 16 bits being zero.

**Edit:** Actually James' answer is the safest (broadest use cases) of all, but the way his answer and mine generalize to other similar problems is a bit different and mine may be more applicable in related problems.

Comment: Why not doing something like `b &= ~(1 ? 0xFFFF : b);` ?